# Casting Statement as COM Object

Tags: c#, comobject

So I know if you assign a variable to a COM Object like `Matrix mtx = form.Items.Item("mtx").Specific;` it needs to be released with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mtx);`

But what if I were to cast it as a COM Object like `((Matrix)form.Items.Item("mtx").Specific).AddRow(1);`.
Now I have no variable reference. Does this get released? Does a reference get created in memory and now it's stuck there until the application is killed?

Take this extension method:

```
 public static T BindControlAs<T>(this BaseFormHandler handler, string itemId) where T : class
    {
        if (!(handler.form.Items.Item(itemId).Specific is T control))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{typeof(T)} failed to bind {itemId}");

        return control;
    }
```

This extension method is used only for my forms COM Objects. Now on my form I can do the following

```
this.BindControlAs<Matrix>("mtx").AddRow(1);
```

Again I have not assigned this to a variable to allow me to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`.

So my question is does a cast or the extension method create a new instance of my COM Object and never gets released and just sits in memory or does it get removed once the statement has been executed?
If it never gets released, is there a way to ensure it does without the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: "Does this get released? Does a reference get created in memory and now it's stuck there until the application is killed?" Yes

Comment: @HimBromBeere so the best approach would be to assign it to a variable and ensure the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is called?

Comment: Yeap, I think so.

Comment: It does not *have* to be released.  This does not work any differently than .NET objects, the garbage collector gets around to it.  The big advantage of .NET, programming COM in a language like C++ is a lot less fun.  Only if the program is wonky and does not generate enough garbage or if you have knowledge that the underlying COM object eats up significant system resources would you ever consider taking control of this.  The biggest source of ReleaseComObject voodoo is Office, an out-of-process server is somewhat special since it doesn't quit when you want it to.  Surely this is just memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your answer would create a reference that is not assigned to a variable, and would be stuck.

You can clean this up by calling Calling `GC.Collect` and then `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` instead of `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` for every COM object.

This is better than assigning every single COM object and then releasing it when you are done with it.

Comment: My questions here is then what is the implications of calling the GC.Collect manually? How does it do a cleanup? Does it cleanup objects in use?

Comment: Calling GC.Collect manually is usually a no-go, but I have had similar situations where it is cleaner than assigning each object to a variable before calling a method.

Comment: This does clean the COM Objects which I didnt know. As Hans Passant said the GC also seems to clean this up automatically which is nice. Just going to leave the small ones and release the big ones with 'Marshal.ReleaseComObject'